# Change background to li tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is simple, but I don't get it as I want it! I want to change the background of li tag when there is a link inside with the class current. I made this, but it only change the background of the link. Help preciated!

```
$("li a.current").css('background-color','yellow');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `a` is direct child of `li`, try

```
$("li a.current").parent().css('background-color','yellow');
```

Answer (score 2):

That only changes the background colour of the link because your selector selects a link! You need to climb back up the DOM tree to get to the `li` element (if you know that the `a` element will always be a direct child of the `li`, see the answer by @rabudde):

`$("li a.current").closest("li").css('background-color','yellow');`

Alternatively, you could use `.has` to filter the set of selected `li` elements:

`$("li").has("a.current").css('background-color', 'yellow');`

Comment: Thanks! That was also some useful alternatives!

Comment: No problem! Just note that if the `a` element at some point becomes a deeper descendant of the `li` (maybe you need to add a `span` or something, for example) then you will have to use `closest` rather than `parent`.